# If two syllables in Mandarin have the same vowels but different tones, can the syllables be said to rhyme?

Tags: phonology, chinese, tone, rhyming

If two syllables in Mandarin have the same vowels but different tones, can the syllables be said to rhyme according to native speakers?

I was tempted to ask this question about all tone languages, but realized that the criteria for rhyming might vary from language to language for all I know.

I will gladly read answers to this question as it relates to other tone languages.

Comment: Would this question be better suited to the [Chinese Language and Usage StackExchange](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/?as=1)?

Comment: In the body of the question, I already explained a) the reason that I asked about Mandarin alone, and b) my interest in analogous findings for other tone languages.

Comment: My bad. Still, a crosspost might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker, I'd say yes to that; 'BUT' they never have to be in same tone to rhyme

Comment: I'm willing to accept native speaker intuitions as data.  The pop-song data in Stumpy Joe Pete's answer seems consistent with Theo lap's statement.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on the meaning of "*can be said to rhyme*". Judgments about the acceptability of rhyming really only make sense in a particular artistic context. I'm using classical Chinese poetry and modern Mandarin pop songs as examples.

### Classical Chinese Poetry

The rules about rhyming in classical Chinese poetry are **complicated**. Syllables which rhymed in Middle-Chinese often don't in Mandarin (and vice versa); in order to even assess whether a poem rhymes properly, you need to look up all the characters' Middle-Chinese tones and so forth. Also, since this style of poetry was being written well after the vernacular pronunciation had changed substantially, the **writers** had to look this stuff up in order to write poems that rhymed.

> [Of the 13-yuán rime] As a so-called 险韵 “treacherous rime,” it was often assigned as the required rhyme on official poetry examinations, so that nervous candidates would mistakenly include words in an<sub>3b</sub> in the rhyme scheme. Or they might include words in an<sub>3a</sub> in a poem whose rhyme scheme was limited to an<sub>3b</sub> and an<sub>4</sub>. In either case, they would be considered to have 出韵 “left the rhyme-scheme”.
>   **...** In late Manchu times, 王闓運 (1833-1916) wrote a poem teasing his colleague 高心夔 (1835-1883), who twice received low scores on the official exams when the appearance of 13-yuán caused him to “leave the rhyme-scheme.” Wáng wrote:
>
> 平生兩四等，該死十三元！
>
> [Two fourth-place finishes in one lifetime — to hell with 13-yuán!]

For a more complete exposition of this, read page 29 to 53 of [this](https://brannerchinese.com/dpb/publications/Branner_MedievalSpelling.pdf).

### Mandarin Pop Songs

Pop songs rhyme. Mostly. Except when they don't. It's pretty much the same as in English pop songs. I did manage to [find](http://www.chinasmack.com/2012/more/chinese-pop-songs/old-boy-by-chopsticks-brothers.html) a couple of approximate rhymes:

> 转眼过去多年世间多少离合悲欢
>
> zhuan3 yan3 guo4 qu4 duo1 nian2 shi4 jian1 duo1 shao3 li2 he2 bei1 huan1
>
> 曾经志在四方少年 羡慕南飞的雁
>
> ceng2 jing1 zhi4 zai4 si4 fang1 shao4 nian2  xian4 mu4 nan2 fei1 de yan4
>
> 各自奔前程的身影 匆匆渐行渐远
>
> ge4 zi4 ben1 qian2 cheng2 de shen1 ying3  cong1 cong1 jian4 xing2 jian4 yuan3
>
> 未来在哪里平凡 啊谁给我答案
>
> wei4 lai2 zai4 na3 li3 ping2 fan2  a shui2 gei3 wo3 da2 an4

Note, that despite the pinyin, huan and yuan do not have the same vowel. Also, yan and an don't either.